# Accessing Certain JSON Elements

Tags: php, json, foreach

How would I go about accessing these elements from a Shopify JSON in PHP

JSON:

```
{  
    "orders":[  
        {   "note_attributes":[  
                {  
                    "name":"field1",
                    "value":"xxxxxxxxxxxx"
                },
                {  
                    "name":"field2",
                    "value":"xxxxxx"
                },
                {  
                    "name":"field3",
                    "value":"xxxxxx"
                }
            ],
```

This is just snippet of the object. How would I access each value and assign it to the name? Eg this $req['account_id'] would equal the value for that name tag. This is how am trying to do it but it's not working:

```
foreach ($order['note_attributes'] as $attributes) {
       
       
        $req = array();
        
 

        $req[$attributes->name] = $attributes[$attributes->value];

    
        }
```

I would then like to echo $req['account_id'] and that would = xxxxxxxxx@gmail.com but it's not working any suggestions or fixes?

Comment: Try [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) and it will convery json into php variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When iterating over Objects properties, one approach is to use (as you have) [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

```
// accessing property
foreach ($objects as $object) {
  echo $object->property;
}

// accessing key-value pair
foreach ($object as $key => $value) {
  echo "$key => $value\n";
}
```

An example:

```
$attributes = array();
.
.
foreach($note_attributes as $note_attribute) {
  $key = $note_attribute['name'];
  $value = $note_attribute['value'];
  $attributes[$key] = $value;
}
```

The structure should be in key-value pairs. ie.

```
attributes [
  "account1234" => "abc@xxx.com",
  "account_password" => "asdasdasd"
]
```

Hope this helps.

**Update**: as Roopendra mentioned, [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) with a TRUE flag with return an associative array, else stdClass.